Moq to NSubstitute AddScoped
I'm new to unit testing, so I'm not sure what I'm looking for. I'm trying to convert a project using Moq to NSubstitute.
Question: How do you convert this line from Moq to NSubstitute
services.AddScoped(provider => Mock.Of<ICurrentUserService>(s => s.UserId == _currentUserId));

EDIT 1:
I tried the following with an error message: The delegate type cannot be inferred
services.AddScoped(provider => Substitute.For<ICurrentUserService>(s => s.UserId == _currentUserId));

This line comes from the CleanArchitectureWithBlazorServer project at this line.
EDIT 2:
ICurrentUserService source:
public interface ICurrentUserService {
    string? UserId { get; }
    string? UserName { get; }
    string? TenantId { get; }
    string? TenantName { get; }
}


What have you tried? What's not working for you?

@MarkSeemann I tried services.AddScoped(provider => Substitutue.For<ICurrentUserService>(s => s.UserId == _currentUserId)); but I get an error at s => saying The delegate type cannot be inferred.

@mjwills I added the source. I'll try your code. I have no idea what to expect except for the tests to pass as I'm not sure what that line does. I see the == _currentUserId and that tells me "get the service where UserId equals the value of _currentUserId." U do believe I'm wrong, but don't know where or what to look for. Thank you.

@mjwills I tried your code, but I just realize (once I posted the source) UserId only has a getter.

@mjwills, yes. It's not my code, it's another project that I'm using to learn Blazor and Clean Architecture, and Unit Testing while I'm it it. :) His (project owner of the link above) uses Moq and that's how it's written. I assume to works as no one's complained nor have I tested. I don't want to use Moq (or test it locally) which is why I'm changing it to use NSubstitute. :)  Hope this helps.

You know what... since my fork of that repo, it looks like the original dev updated something to use ICurrentUserAccessor, still has a similar like with ==. I'mma check what this new interface is.

The google query you want is nsubstitute readonly property.

I'm so sorry. I'm not sure how that helps. In Moq what is that line doing so I can understand it? When I see it, I don't believe it's setting/initializing the value of UserId, and doing something beyond my understanding. I haven't been successful in finding samples doing the what this line does. Now, if it is setting/initializing the value, then I understand a bit better and I'm thinking of using something like Substitutue.For<ICurrentUserService>.Returns(_currentUserId). I appreciate all your help.

It is trying to mock a readonly property. I'm thinking of using something like Did that work?

Seems to have worked! Thanks!

A review of the documentation here would have shown you how configure properties on the mock
Based on the interface provided in your example and code it is meant to replace, it would look something like this:
services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService>(provider => {
    var mock = Substitute.For<ICurrentUserService>()
    mock.UserId.Returns(_currentUserId);
    
    //...set other properties as needed
    
    return mock;
});

If you review the main documentation, it should help you get a better understanding of this .Net mocking library

Thank you! I was there and I did read this. I just wasn't sure if that's what I needed. I'll try that now.

Worked! Thanks!
